# UIActivityViewController in GameScene

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want to use this function in my GameScene:

```
 func shareButton(){
   var myShare = "test"
   let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare],          applicationActivities: nil)
   self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion:nil)
 }
```

Because I am using a spritenode and when the spritenode is pushed, I want the sharebutton function to run. but as far as I know an `UIActivitycontroller` can not be in GameScene, only in `GameViewController`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it in the GameViewController, no other way around.